# How to fix: NullPointerException in JpaCriteriaQueryBackend.getOrderList

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, crnk

I setup on a Java EE 7.0 server (Oracle WebLogic) using 3.0.20190714142556 with a simple resource (customer) loaded as JPA Entity with JpaEntityRepositoryBase from a database. The application can be deployed without problems. crnk.io will be used with JAX-RS in this application. However when accessing the resource (customer) with findAll() I got a NullPointerException in `JpaCriteriaQueryBackend.getOrderList()`.

Tried to use the application in Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.3 and also Payara Server. In both cases the same error occurred.

The following code line in this class returns a null instead of an empty list I guess: criteriaQuery.getOrderList().

```
@Override
  public List<Order> getOrderList() {
     return new ArrayList<>(criteriaQuery.getOrderList());

  }
```

Currently a NullPointerException was reported in line 109 of JpaCriteriaQueryBackend. Expected is that all available customers will be loaded as result.

Expected result is to get the list of customers from the database.

[complete stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjDur.png)

Comment: Are you sure `criteriaQuery` is not null?

Comment: Aren't you getting a timeout error?

Comment: yes, criteriaQuery is not null. The problem is that getOrderList doesn't return an empty list, it returns null.

Comment: I didn't got a timeout error.

Comment: I made a test with a bugfix for this function: `java.util.List<Order> orderedList = criteriaQuery.getOrderList();
    if (orderedList != null) {
      return new ArrayList<>(criteriaQuery.getOrderList());
    } else {
      return new ArrayList<>();
    }` This works as expected. Seems to be a bug?